# What do the elements of a ring $R/I$ look like?

Tags: polynomial-rings

I am a bit confused, as my class is currently on Section 9.2 of Dummit and Foote, and what elements of $R/I$ are of the form of, where $R$ is a polynomial ring.

For example, I am reading that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2)$ are of the form $a + bx + cy + dxy$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. How is this deduced?

I suppose there is a definition $R/I = \{ r + I, r \in R \}$, but how does this form $a + bx + cy + dxy$, and can anyone give some other examples of how we can write elements of $R/I$ with a polynomial ring?

How should I be thinking about this more deeply?

Comment: What is $y$ referring to in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,y^2,2)$? Did you mean to write $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes, I will edit this.

Comment: It isn't particularly deep. If something is a multiple of $2$ or $x^2$ or $y^2$, it is $0$ in this ring. You reduce elements of the ring by this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of quotienting by an ideal as a way of making the elements in the ideal become $0$. A simple example is $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ which is just the ring with elements $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. We've made $6 = 0$ which in turn meant that $7 = 1, 8 = 2, ...$. In your example we are making $x^2, y^2$ and $2$ equal $0$. Having $x^2$ be $0$ means that any term of the form $ ax^ny^m = 0$ if $n \ge 2$. We have a similar situation for $y^2$. This means that your polynomial can only have the form $ a + bx + cy + dxy $ since the higher order terms will be $0$. The reason why the coefficients are in $Z_2$ is because we have quotiented by $2$ which means $2 = 0$. Hence all even numbers are actually $0$ since they can be written as $2n = 2\cdot 0 = 0$. All odd numbers are just equal to $1$ since they can be written as $2n + 1 = 2 \cdot 0 + 1 = 1$.

Comment: This is actually really helpful. Thank you for this, I'm not sure why I haven't seen this kind of explanation anywhere else.

Comment: One other note: elements of the quotient ring are technically equivalence classes, i.e. $[4]\in\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not the same element as $4\in\mathbb{Z}_6$, because $\{\dots,-2,4,10,\dots\}\in[4]$. (haha I forgot I don't have my usual macros here)